# VideoView Problems

Tags: android

everyone,
I'm a bloody beginner with Android Studio and Java.
I wrote a simple splash video when the app starts.
Unfortunately the video is displayed in a very small format.
I would like to see it as a full screen video - unfortunately I already tried everything on the internet.

I wrote all this about MainActivity without an xml.
Can someone please tell me what I have to write to play the video fullscreen?
And maybe - that the screen rotates when you turn the phone over?

I apologize for my bad english
I hope someone can help me.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class splash_demo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle sa){
        super.onCreate(sa);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        try{
            VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
            setContentView(videoView);
            Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.google.fotz/" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.r2131427328);
            videoView.setVideoURI(path);

            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)   {
                    jump();
                }
            });
            videoView.start();
        }catch (Exception e){
            jump();
        }


    }
    private void jump() {

        if(isFinishing())
            return;
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

Please help!

Comment: Would be helpful if you can post the XML layout and screenshots.

Comment: its a standart Layout xml when you start a new Project.
I write all in MainActivity ... not in the Layout xml. 
Here is the code :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: This is a bad practice. Design should be done predominantly in the XML layout.